# dd.mm.yyyy format in jQuery tableSorter

Tags: javascript, jquery, date, tablesorter

I'd like to add a parser to jQuery TableSorter which allows a column to be sorted by date on the **dd.mm.yyyy** format, for instance **17.09.2011**.

I tried the following, based on some code I found online:

```
$.tablesorter.addParser({
    // set a unique id 
    id: 'myDateFormat',
    is: function (s) {
        return false;
    },
    format: function (s) {
        var date = s.split('.');
        return new Date(date[2], date[1], date[0]).getTime();
    },
    type: 'numeric'
});
```

Then:

```
$(".myTable").tablesorter( { headers: { 3: { sorter: 'myDateFormat'} } } );
```

However, this doesn't work... Any idea why?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems to work for me - [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/8cg4f/1/)

The demo is using my [forked version](https://github.com/Mottie/tablesorter) of tablesorter, but that shouldn't change how your parser works.

Answer (score 1):

try

```
// add parser through the tablesorter addParser method
$.tablesorter.addParser({
    // set a unique id 
    id: 'clDate',
    is: function (s) {
        // return false so this parser is not auto detected 
        return false;
    },
    format: function (s) {
        // format your data for normalization 
        var date = s.split("-");
        var result = (parseInt(date[2]) * 10000 + parseInt(date[1]) * 100 + parseInt(date[0]));
        return result;
    },
    // set type, either numeric or text 
    type: 'numeric'
});
```